# Convert a string with Unicode characters in decimal format(html encoded) to a regular string

Tags: java, string, unicode, hashmap

I have one variable of type Map.

```java
if (sourceMap.containsKey(currentRow)) {
    //Remove the row from Map
} else {
    //Mismatch
}
```

where `sourceMap` is a Hashmap variable which contains many strings such as

```
Period Name
Person Last Name
Person First Name
Order Code
Ship_to_Customer_Name
Sub_Profit_Center
Commission Amount
Credit Amount
Rate Amount
Apr-09
Morgan
Martin
1022334852
Carl Zeiss de M&# 195;&# 189;xico, S.A. de C.V.(no space after the # in the string)
```

and `currentRow` contains the following string:

```
Carl Zeiss de MÃ½xico, S.A. de C.V.
```

which is same as the last row.My requirement is It should match. Now it is not matching.What conversion I have to do to match those

These strings are from different files
first one is downloaded as CSV so no unicode characters..and second one(currentRow) is downloaded in unicoded txt format and converted to CSV using dos2unix..

Comment: That "current row" looks like you've applied the wrong encoding when converting it from binary to text. Please give more information about where the values are coming from - I suspect you need to solve the problem earlier.

Comment: encoding error `&# 195;&# 189;` different from `Ã½`

Comment: The string `Carl Zeiss de "M&# 195;&# 189;xico, S.A. de C.V.` (even with the invalid spaces in the entities removed) is not the same as the string `Carl Zeiss de MÃ½xico, S.A. de C.V.` In two different ways: 1. The first one uses (or tries to use) HTML character entities (which are nothing special to Java), and 2. The first one has a quote before the capital `M` that the second one doesn't have. For reference, [Unicode escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) in Java look like this: `\uXXXX` (where `X` is a hex digit).

Comment: updated the question..double quote typed mistakenly and no space after the #symbol

Comment: These strings are from different files first one is downloaded as CSV so no unicode characters..and second one(currentRow) is downloaded in unicoded txt format and converted to CSV using dos2unix..

Comment: @user2504445: It's still there (the space).

Comment: If I remove the space both Strings will become same..So you people will start saying both are same so it should match..

Comment: Nobody is there to answer my question???  Do you have any doubt whether these strings are same...then just click on add question and type the string(without space after the # symbol) then you will see both strings are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Carl Zeiss de M&#195;&#189;xico, S.A. de C.V.
```

This is a string with HTML-encoded characters in it. You can do an HTML-unescape using a utility function such as [`unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29).

Generally you want to keep your strings in raw form rather than with HTML-escapes in them. Look at wherever it is you got your `sourceMap` - if you control that and can fix it avoid the gratuitous escaping then this would have just worked. Note also that `MÃ½xico`, whether HTML-encoded or not, looks like evidence of mishandling Unicode characters somewhere else in the stack.

Comment: Greate...Thanks....It has worked..just curious.will there be any impact for other strings..I have checked for other strings and found no problem ,just for clarification i am asking..

Answer (score 0):

First we have to download the jar file from the following url http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonlang3jar.htm

Now add the import statement as follows

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4;
```

Now we need to use the method where we want to escape the html encoded string.
for eg:

```
String s=Carl Zeiss de M&#195;&#189;xico, S.A. de C.V.
System.out.println("Before: "+s);
s=unescapeHtml4(s);
System.out.println("After: "+s);
```

Now the output will be as follows

```
Before: Carl Zeiss de M&#195;&#189;xico, S.A. de C.V. 
After: Carl Zeiss de MÃ½xico, S.A. de C.V.
```